# GAN generates the same image during each epoch

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I'm such a beginner in the context of generative adversarial networks and representation learning.My goal is to train a simple gan using dense layers to generate fashion mnist images.I've tried many codes online which had given successful outputs to everyone but in my case all of them produce the same output which is a blank white image with some dots in particular areas frequently.I also checked the activation functions but they seem to be fine.Also to mention that I run my code in google colab.Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist


(X_train, _), (X_test, _) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

def plot_images(images, n_cols):
    n_rows = (len(images) - 1) // n_cols + 1
    if images.shape[-1] == 1:
        images = np.squeeze(images, axis=-1)
    plt.figure(figsize=(n_cols, n_rows))
    for index, image in enumerate(images):
        plt.subplot(n_rows, n_cols, index + 1)
        plt.imshow(image, cmap="binary")
        plt.axis("off")
    plt.show()

codings_size = 100
generator = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="selu", input_shape=[codings_size]),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation="selu"),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(28 * 28, activation="sigmoid"),
 tf.keras.layers.Reshape([28, 28])
])

discriminator = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
 tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28]),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation="selu"),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="selu"),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])
gan = tf.keras.models.Sequential([generator, discriminator])
discriminator.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop")
discriminator.trainable = False
gan.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="rmsprop")
batch_size = 32
n_epochs = 50
for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    print("Epoch {}/{}".format(epoch + 1, n_epochs))   
    for i in range(len(X_train) // batch_size):
        X_batch = X_train[i: i+batch_size]

        noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=[batch_size, codings_size])
        generated_images = generator(noise)
        X_fake_and_real = np.concatenate([generated_images, X_batch], axis=0)
        y1 = np.array([[0.]] * batch_size + [[1.]] * batch_size)
        discriminator.trainable = True
        discriminator.train_on_batch(X_fake_and_real, y1)

        noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=[batch_size, codings_size])
        y2 = np.array([[1.]] * batch_size)
        discriminator.trainable = False
        gan.train_on_batch(noise, y2)
    plot_images(generated_images, 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [mode collapse](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/gan/problems#mode-collapse) where generator keeps producing same or similar outputs and discriminator fails to reject it. It also could be due to some problem in your implementation.

Try training the discriminator first for one or your chosen `K` steps before training generator.

Keras have many have simple examples for GAN. You can modify below DCGAN implementation to work with fashion mnist.

https://keras.io/examples/generative/dcgan_overriding_train_step/

https://keras.io/examples/generative/

Comment: Thank you for the answer.I'm actually training the discriminator first in the given code.The referred links did indeed work for me which i'm glad.I modified the data by applying this `X_train = (X_train - 127.5)/127.5` and also changed the activation function of the last layer of the generator to tangent hyperbolic which made the model to fall into mode collapse after 10 epochs.Is it natural for a model to fall into mode collapse this early?The previous model fell into mode collapse from the beginning.